# Ceaser's Cipher

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, caesar-cipher

Here's a Java Code for Ceaser's cipher

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length = stdin.nextInt();
    String text = stdin.next();
    int shift = stdin.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            System.out.print((char)(((int)c - (int)'a' + shift) % 26 + (int)'a'));
        } else if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
            System.out.print((char)(((int)c - (int)'A' + shift) % 26 + (int)'A'));
        } else {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
    stdin.close();
}
}
```

and i cannot understand what is happening at this line of code

```
System.out.print((char)(((int)c - (int)'a' + shift) % 26 + (int)'a'));
```

why do   **-( int ) ' a '**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the ASCII values.. letter a has ascii value of 97, A has ascii value of 65.

I hope you understand how ceaser cipher works.

if you have ABCD as your original text and you want to do a shift of 1 to apply ceaser cipher, it means A will be B, B will be C, C will be D and D will be E.

length is your string length, text is your original text, shift is by how many shifts in alphabets you want to apply ceaser cipher.

Lets take a sample text: abcd

with shift 1

for now lets assume c value is 'a'

so this statement is `(int)c - (int)'a' + shift) % 26 + (int)'a')`

will typically do (97-97+1)%26+97

```
(1%26)+97
1+97 
98
```

which is ascii equivalent of b. that is why in your code the entire operation is converted to char at the end:

```
**(char)**(((int)c - (int)'a' + shift) % 26 + (int)'a')
```

Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 3):

In order for the % 26 to correctly rotate the encoded character when the shift would push it beyond 'z', you need to be dealing with values 0-25. The ASCII values of 'a' - 'z' are 97-122, making the rotation difficult. By subtracting 'a' from the character being shifted, you are mapping the character to a value from 0-25, making the rotation possible using % 26.

Answer (score 1):

as "Max Hampton" said, the values of the letters in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) starts from 97 (in the small letters case).

so therefore if for example you have the letter `c='p'` then c = 112. also 'a'=97, so 'p'-'a' = 112-97 = 15 (note: p is place 16 in the alphabet).

now we add the shift (although p is now moved 1 step back, be we will fix it in a moment). lets the the shift is 3 (we want p->s)

now we got 15+3 = 18. 18%26 = 18.

now for the fix: 18 + 'a' = 18+97 = 115 = 's' (the 1 is back here)

and done :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int Ceasers_Cipher()
{
    int y;
    string x;
    int r;
    cout << "enter any sentence" << endl;
    getline(cin, x);
    y = x.size();
    cout << "enter rotation" << endl;
    cin >> r;
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        if (x[i] >= 'a' && x[i] <= 'a'+(26-r))
        {
            x[i] += r;
        }
        else if (x[i] >= 'a' + (26 - r)+1 && x[i] <= 'z')
        {
            x[i] -= 26-r;
        }
        else if (x[i] >= 'A' && x[i] <= 'A' + (26 - r))
        {
            x[i] +=r;
        }
        else if (x[i]>='A' + (26 - r) + 1 && x[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            x[i] -= 26-r;
        }
    }
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    Ceasers_Cipher();
}
```

Comment: What do you want to show with this post that was not already answered?